# one function for 3 scenarios

Tags: functions, exponential-function, mathematical-modeling

Just wondering, is there a function that depends and a small number of parameters and can model these 3 scenarios (depending on the chosen parameters):

[image]

The first is a constant, the second a log-normal (?) and the 3rd a decay function. Thanks!

Comment: @NiklasvMoers thanks. This has to be purely data driven. I do not want to learn the "decision" as to which function to chose, if that makes sense? Mind you whether to have the constant or the other 2 functions depends on a 2 level factor IV.

Comment: I deleted my comment and gave an explicit formula to transform between two functions. Is that more in the lines of what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have two functions $f_0, f_1: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then you have a continuous deformation ("homotopy") between those two functions given by
$$ f: \mathbb{R} \times [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x, t) := (1-t) f_0(x) + t f_1(x). $$
It has the property $f(x, 0) = f_0(x)$ and $f(x, 1) = f_1(x)$. This generalizes easily to any number of functions.

Edit: I thought of another way without case distintion to generalize this to any number of cases: Define the [standard-n-simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex) $\Delta^n$ by
$$ \{ (t_0, t_1, ..., t_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \mid t_i \geq 0, \sum t_i = 1 \}.$$
Then you can define your "homotopy" function $f$ by

$$f: \mathbb{R} \times \Delta^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x, (t_0, t_1, ..., t_n)) := \sum\limits_i t_i f_i(x). $$
This looks kind of complicated, but you can imagine it like this: The closer you go to a vertex of your simplex (e.g. your triangle), the closer you go to one of your function $f_i$.

Comment: thanks. the solution of using t is exactly what I need. I also just realized that the log normal can be like a decay function. Thanks! You say this generalizes to any number of functions. In fact, I have the 2 factors. One with 2 levels (like I described) and another with 12 levels (months). The 2 level one determines whether it is a constant or not. The amplitude and shape of the other functions depend on the month.

Comment: The way that this generalizes is that you consider $f: \mathbb{R} \times [0, n] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and make a case distinction in which interval $[i, i+1]$ your parameter $t$ is where $i$ is a natural number.

Comment: great generalization thanks.